# Rich Snippet Recipe does not show image

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to get the image of an recipe to the search results of google. It does not work and i do not know why?

I have schema semantics for recipes which, due to google rich snippet testing tool are working fine, but when i search for "Vietnamesische Sommerrollen", theres is no image.

Here is an example URL: https://asiastreetfood.com/rezepte/vietnamesische-sommerrollen/

Any ideas what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the whole structure of my code to fit the needs of the recipe schema.org. As it seems, you have to be very clean and not wrapping to much around the schema-markup. Not it works even with the pictures shown in google search results. Example Markup can be found here: [Pho Bo Hanoi](https://asiastreetfood.com/rezepte/pho_bo_hanoi/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a same Problem and the rating star also not showing , but I'm sure the problem from google because they change the [Rich Snippets tool](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fstructured-data%2Ftesting-tool%2F&ei=-KcpVcqjNpTwaOXRgOgG&usg=AFQjCNFb_UstK12eRd78nJTDN4d0i3h3jA&sig2=YLPROd__AljGFXa4eVSTIA) in there sit

Answer (score 0):

Try to have your image use `http` insteand of `https`.

Also note that all information set within the schema will be used by search engines all the time. They still get to decide what is relevant/safe to display to users.